# Avoiding gritty cockles

Tags: seafood

Is there any way I can identify whether or not a cockle is likely to contain grit *before* I bite down on it? I don't mean by cutting it open before hand, but a visual identification. General shade/darker areas don't seem to correlate with the amount of grit.

They're so tasty but I really don't like it when that happens...

For information, I buy them ready cooked but from the fish counter in the supermarket (not the ones in jars which are usually farmed and grit free).

Comment: The cockle vendor is not taking the time to let the cockles flush the grit, most likely because it takes time and should happen in salt water, both inconveniences.  I rake clams in the Peconic Bay estuary system and flush them twice using fresh bay saltwater each time for at least two hours each time.  After that NO GRIT EVER.